# table Header should be show at the Head of each page during print in html

Tags: html

I would like to show header on page during print. So the I use code which is:

```
<table align="center">
    <thead style="display: table-header-group;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Header
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> Body data</tbody>
</table>
```

Header and content are show correct on localhost. But Issue is when we host on server header not show on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code in jsfiddle places the body content above header, uncentered. The header content is below body and is centered.

```
<table align="center">
    <thead style="display: table-header-group;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Header
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Body data
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code is a lot closer to yours, just added tr and td for the body section. This includes it in the table and styles it accordingly.

Currently you have a table with a header and a separate body section.

Comment: if you don't mind would you please elaborate you answer.